# Get id from Swing component in Groovy SwingBuilder

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder

Let's say I declare an object using SwingBuilder as follows:

`swing.button(id:'something')`

I know I can get the `Component` back from SwingBuilder by calling:

`swing."something"`

But how can I go from an instance of the `Component`, *back* to its `id` as a String?

```
Component c = getMyButton()
String whatIWant = c.id    //Property doesn't exist
String attempt2  = c['id'] //Property doesn't exist
```

Comment: Do you have complete code sample to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the *name*, so [`Component#getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName--) should do what you want.

For example:

```
Component c = getMyButton()
String whatIWant = c.getName() // or c.name
```

Unfortunately, this is not documented, but [it appears to be what the Groovy SwingBuilder source does](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b/subprojects/groovy-swing/src/main/groovy/groovy/swing/SwingBuilder.groovy#L496), though [perhaps only when there is no explicit `.id` property](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b/subprojects/groovy-swing/src/main/groovy/groovy/swing/SwingBuilder.groovy#L119) (one does not exist on `Component`..?)